# Is it possible to mix spring xml configuration with java

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I am using spring framework 4.1.4

I have JBoss5XmlWebApplicationContext as my contextClass reading xml configuration.

I want to add @Configuration class to be read aside from the xml.
Is this possible? How to do it?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible. One way I know is using springboot classes. I am using MySpringConfiguration class to declare beans using @Configuration and MySpringConfig.xml for xml based bean configuration. I am able to load beans from the context coming from both sources.
Check below code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Resource res = new FileSystemResource("E:\\MySpringConfig.xml");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MySpringConfiguration.class,res);
        ApplicationContext ctx = app.run("");
        MyXMLBean myXMLBean = (MyXMLBean)ctx.getBean("myNewBean"); // From XML file...  
        GeData geData= (GeData)ctx.getBean("geData"); // From Java Configuration ...
        ....
```

Configuration class goes like this

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GeData geData(){
        return new GeData();
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Although this does answer the titles question,
but it doesn't answer the specific case i'm refering to about mixing with
JBoss5XmlWebApplicationContext. I'll up vote it anyhow for the effort, thanks. (dang i don't have the reps enough to upvote .. lol)

Comment: I believe JBoss5XmlWebApplicationContext can also be loaded, you may check SpringApplication APIs and there you can check methods(maybe load()) which loads beans def from other sources into any context which implements ApplicationContext.